# Sum Value of The Column in Telerik Report

Tags: visual-studio, telerik, report, telerik-reporting

Hi I have a simple yet confusing problem when creating Telerik Report in Visual Studio.
Is it possible to set the value of textbox from table value ?

```
| Score    | Total Score | Weight    | Total Score   |
------------------------------------------------------
| 3        | 5           | 20%       | 1             |
| 2        |             |           |               |
------------------------------------------------------
| 4        | 4           | 10%       | 0.4           |
------------------------------------------------------
| 5        | 5           | 5%        | 0.25          |
```

I have a textbox to show the sum of Total Score column, so it will have 1.65 as the value. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using Expression :

```
|      Score      |     Total Score     |      Weight     |                Total Score             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| = Fields.score  | =Sum(Fields.score)  | = Fields.Weight | =Sum(Fields.score)*(Fields.Weight/100) |
```